# Rationale behind python method naming for string.find and list.index

Tags: python, language-design

I wonder why people named these methods differently even though they're doing almost the same job. Wouldn't it be easier to understand/remember if they had the same name?

According to documentations of [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), they look like they are pretty much the same thing to me.

> ```
> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is
>   equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.
>
> The optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in the slice
>   notation and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence
>   of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning
>   of the full sequence rather than the start argument.
>
> ```
> string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such
>   that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
>   the same as for slices.

Comment: There's a `str.index` that more closely matches `list.index`. `str.find` behaves differently when there's no match.

Comment: (Both `str.index` and `str.find` have a major difference from `list.index` in that they test for substrings instead of elements, though.)

Comment: Oh thank you I did not know that. :)

Comment: @user2357112 I think this should be an answer

Comment: I agree with @Marat